# Notify UI from OkHttp Interceptor

Tags: android, okhttp, interceptor

I need to change UI based on boolean value in interceptor (i get to know it only inside interceptor and it never leaves it).

**Possible solution I though of:**
Create handler like `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` and then do `.post(new Runnable()..)`, but I don't want to mess UI logic into Interceptor class.

Comment: Just a quick question, why do you have to do that? It seems a little bit off to me.

Comment: @barotia I make some requests and then in interceptor (already designed, can't change) check whether running device is ok. in case it's not I want to display message in UI.

Comment: Legacy code? :D So much fun, anyway if you do not have time to redesign, my first thought was the content providers and rxjava, however, it depends on the complexity of project, tbh it's seems a little bit overkill to use CP and RX for this, but delegating listeners, well it can be messy.

Comment: Do you use java or kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

1. Add following dependency to your `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
}
```

2. Create class for holding data that comes from interceptor:

```java
public static class InterceptorEvent { /* Add fields you need */ }
```

3. In your interceptor, post event using following code:

```java
EventBus.getDefault().post(new InterceptorEvent());
```

4. Subscribe to `InterceptorEvent` wherever you need:

```java
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onInterceptorEvent(InterceptorEvent event) {
    // Do whatever you want
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

I hope my answer helps.

Comment: Nice one, just a single question, is this supported at the moment?

Comment: Last commit has been made 6 month ago. However, I have been using it in some of production projects and haven’t seen any big issues with it yet.

Comment: @barotia you can achieve it with LiveData if you want smth that is supported.

Comment: I would stay at rx or just simple contentproviders, the live data is not really work, if you start to work from multiple threads, and anyway, it's not the main purpose.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not defending the idea that you should always use EventBus library but it's helpful, especially, when you have legacy code that you don't have time to refactor.